# How to determine and increase the number of mapper and reducer process/threads in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo, bigdata, database

I am trying to increase the number of mapper and reducer process / threads in MongoDB map reduce. I am using Python client called PyMongo. I was not able to find an documentation regarding this in Mongo docs.

Comment: I don't know if mongo gives you that kind of power, https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/ You can take a look at your UNIX ulimit settings and see where they are at, see [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/) [![](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BztDp.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BztDp.png)